# Two processes bound to different cpu cores affect each other

Tags: linux, operating-system, schedule

I have two different processes A and B and they are bound to diffenrent cpu cores. A is bound to cpu cores: 0-4 and B is bound to cpu cores: 8-12.
After A's CPU usage is doubled, B's processing speed is slow.
When I kill A，the B's  processing speed is fast.
If I kill A, and use `stress-ng` simulation A to stress test on CPU cores 0-4,B's processing speed is slow. What could be causing this problem? A and B are obviously running on different CPU cores.

Comment: It could be contention for RAM bandwidth.  It could be contention for I/O.  It could be virtual memory thrashing.  There are lots of possibilities.  However, this is not a programming question.  It is primarily a question about OS level performance diagnosis and tuning.

Comment: @StephenC thanks, I think so. Is there any tool to find the specific problem? Or any suggestions for performance optimization?

Comment: I would start with tools like `top`, `iostat` and `vmstat`.  But you would be better off asking on a different site!